# sqlplus unable to find DB instance

Tags: linux, oracle11g

I have a linux server OEL 5.8 in which 8 oracle DB instances are running. 4 Db instances are running on Oracle 10.2.0.4 and other 4 on 11.2.0.3. Initially, all the DB instances were running on 10.2.0.4. I upgraded 4 of them to 11.2.0.3. Now the existing linux server is going to be migrated on new location. Server was cloned to the new server location and I got the exact replica of my old server at new location. I was able to start the Oracle 10g DB instances perfectly fine just changing the hostname in tnsnames.ora and listener.ora. However I am unable to start ORacle 11g instances. sqlplus is unable to find the Db instance. $ORACLE_SID, $ORACLE_HOME and $PATH are set to oracle 11g location in environment variables. Pfile exists in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs. But when I try to connect like 'sqlplus / as sysdba' I am unable to find any idle instnace to start.

```
flow81 > echo $ORACLE_HOME
        /dboracle/orabase/product/11.2.0.3
flow81 > echo $PATH
        /dboracle/orabase/product/11.2.0.3/bin
flow81 > echo $ORACLE_SID
         flow81
flow81 > sqlplus / as sysdba

       SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Sep 19 05:58:01 2017

       Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

       Connected.
       SQL>
```

For DB instances in 10g,

```
      fltr81 > sqlplus / as sysdba

      SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Tue Sep 19 06:00:10 2017

      Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

      Connected to an idle instance.
      SQL> STARTUP
      ORACLE instance started.

    Total System Global Area  159383552 bytes
    Fixed Size                  2082464 bytes
    Variable Size             113248608 bytes
    Database Buffers           37748736 bytes
    Redo Buffers                6303744 bytes
    Database mounted.
    Database Opened.
```

My question is why sqlplus is unable to find idle instance in oracle 11g to start them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some configuration issue in /etc/hosts. IP was mapped against some different hostname, hence the issue. After mapping IP to correct Hostname issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simply if your Database is already started up, sqlplus will connect to the instance. If instance is not started up, sqlplus will connect to an idle instance by default. Moreover if you want to connect with a specific instance you have to specify @SID_NAME as follows in the sqlplus command

sqlplus / as sysdba@SID

Comment: I tried as you told.   sqlplus / as sysdba@flow83

    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Sep 25 06:22:21 2017

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    Connected.
    SQL> STARTUP
    ORA-00000: normal, successful completion
  SQL> Getting ORA-00000 error